# Splitting up a few big tables into multiple ones and avoiding empty tables

Tags: postgresql, functions, condition

I am in the process of restructurizing and unifying a large database in PostgreSQL. One part of this is to split up some large tables into smaller ones according to their value in 'key'. The function I have written for this works well and looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_tables (table_string varchar(100)) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
r_row record;

BEGIN
FOR r_row IN SELECT type FROM type_list
LOOP
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE public.id_' || table_string || '__' || r_row.type || ' AS (SELECT * FROM id_'
|| table_string || ' WHERE lower(id_' || table_string || '.key) = lower(''' || r_row.type || '''));';
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpsql;
```

So, this goes through all entries in type_list and creates tables for each type. To do this for all tables that need to be split I call this function with
`SELECT tobesplit.id FROM tobesplit, LATERAL split_tables(tobseplit.id);`

However, this creates tables for ALL entries in type_list, even if there are no entries in the table to be split for some types. So in the end, I create a whole bunch of empty tables that I don't need. I looked for ways to only create tables if the result is not empty, and found a possible solution in the answer for: [CREATE TABLE IF ONLY NOT EMPTY RESULT SET](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284449/create-table-if-only-not-empty-result-set).

This works if I test it seperately, but I have no idea how to incorporate this into the exectue statement. I always get syntax errors as soon as I write an IF or CASE-clause into the EXECUTE statement.

I am thankful for any ideas :)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance of PostGreSQL, but why not just Partition the table?

Comment: Well, a lot of the data over the past few years has been stored in various different formats, and some of it is already in the format that I'm trying to get to; which I also think is the most useful for the types of queries that will be important.

In the large tables I will not need 95% of the info when running a query from it since the measurements stored in them are vastly different from each other. So I thought splitting them up and merging with the already existing ones in the format is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change

```
FOR r_row IN SELECT type FROM type_list
```

to

```
FOR r_row IN
   EXECUTE format(
              'SELECT DISTINCT lower(key) AS type FROM %I',
              'id_' || table_string
           )
```

I would suggest that you use list partitioning and lump all the keys that don't exist anywhere into a single partition.

Comment: I like the idea, this would be pretty elegant. The problem is that the EXECUTE statement in the loop throws an error since r_row does not have the column type or key anymore. And if I try with r_row without any additional argument, I just get one empty table id_tablestring__

Comment: Fixed the query.

Comment: This works great, thank you very much! (It needs a SELECT DISTINCT or CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS, if anybody else encounters this problem, but I had planned on using the latter one anyway)